# The aggregation function specifies the field order for processing, and after aggregation, each group returns the specified size data and terminates

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, aggregation, postgresql-11

First of all thanks for your help.
`sorted_id` is the id sorted after `group_id` grouping. I hope to aggregate according to `group_id` and return in `sorted_id` order. And can specify the number of returns (like required num), for example, specify the first 3 returns of each group, If the `content` has a high similarity among the first three, it will be filtered out, and then so on, until three pieces of data are returned.

```
Table
_id   group_id   content    sorted_id   
0        2          tab      1          
1        2          name     2           
2        1          tag      1           
3        1          bag      2           
4        1          a        3           
5        2          b        3         
6        1          bo       4           
7        2          an       4
```

expected
like `tag` and `bag` was similarity will filter `bag` for group_id 1. and like 'tab' and 'tac' for group_id 2 will filter tac. because of sorted_id order.

In fact, I only need to filter based on the first N content of each group, and filter out if there are similar values. In order to avoid traversing all the data, I hope to process according to sorted_id, and terminate if it is satisfied. The result is similar to this.

```
_id   group_id   content    sorted_id   
0        2          tab      1                    
2        1          tag      1                     
4        1          a        3           
5        2          b        3         
6        1          bcca     4           
7        2          an       4
```

I wrote some plpgsql functions, but I have no good ideas.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION similarity_str(content_array text[], content text, similarity_threshold float, required_num integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    store_content text;
    similarity float;
    is_ok bool := FALSE;
BEGIN

        IF array_length(content_array, 1)= required_num THEN
            RETURN 0;
            END IF;

        IF sentence_info is NULL THEN
            sentence_info := array_append(sentence_info, content);
        ELSE
        FOREACH store_content IN ARRAY sentence_info
            LOOP
                EXECUTE format('select similarity($1, $2)')using store_content, content INTO similarity;
             
                IF similarity>similarity_threshold THEN
                    is_ok := FALSE;
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
                is_ok := TRUE;
            END LOOP;
        if is_ok THEN
            sentence_info := array_append(sentence_info, content);
            is_ok := FALSE;
            RETURN 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
 
    RETURN 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thank you very much for reading this.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the dynamic SQL is unnecessary here. You can use `similarity := similarity(store_content, content);` which is more efficient

Comment: see you again, thanks.